# How do I draw the plot of a function between two horizontal boundaries?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need help plotting a function between two horizontal lines. I have a complex function consisting of several linear piecewise functions (more complex than in the picture). There are 2 horizontal boundaries that the function should not cross. If the graph is between these lines and does not cross these boundaries, it is drawn as is. If it intersects the lower boundary, the graph is not displayed further (after this point it is not displayed above or below the line). When the upper line is intersected, the graph moves along that boundary until the function starts to decrease. I have tried to show in the figure what I want to get (in blue). Please note that the value of the graph is equal to the upper limit only while the function is increasing(!!!), not when the value is greater than this limit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))
x = np.linspace(1, 22, num=1000)
y = np.zeros(1000)
mask1 = (1 <= x) & (x <= 3)
mask2 = (3 < x) & (x <= 5)
mask3 = (5 < x) & (x <= 6)
mask4 = (6 < x) & (x <= 8)
mask5 = (8 < x) & (x <= 10)
mask6 = (10 < x) & (x <= 11)
mask7 = (11 < x) & (x <= 13)
mask8 = (13 < x) & (x <= 15)
mask9 = (15 < x) & (x <= 20)
mask10 = (20 < x) & (x <= 22)
y[mask1] = 2.5 * x[mask1] - 0.5
y[mask2] = 17.5 - 3.5 * x[mask2]
y[mask3] = 2 * x[mask3] - 10
y[mask4] = x[mask4] - 4
y[mask5] = 5.5 * x[mask5] - 40
y[mask6] = 15
y[mask7] = -6.5 * x[mask7] + 173 / 2
y[mask8] = 2 * x[mask8] - 24
y[mask9] = -3 * x[mask9] + 51
y[mask10] = 5 * x[mask10] - 109
border = 5
border2 = -6
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.axhline(border, color='lightgreen')
plt.axhline(border2, color='lightgreen')
plt.plot(x, y, color="r")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Above code only gives one line - red one. Are you looking to cut off that line at 5 and -6? Is that the requirement?

Comment: @Redox 5 and -6 are limits that the graph cannot cross. "cut off" is not quite right. Project what is greater than 5 onto the upper boundary, and if the differential is less than 0, then the function begins to decrease from that point, parallel to the red line
And if the function is -6, then the cutoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the code per below. Basically, I am creating a new array yblue which will move up and down as per your conditions. Add this code in place of `plt.plot(x, y, color="r")`... last two lines..

Note that I am assuming that the blue line CAN go below border2 (-6). Let me know otherwise...

```
yblue=[]
delta=0
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] < border2: #Less than border2, stop plotting
        break
    elif y[i] <= border: # In between, continue
        yblue.append(y[i] - delta)
    else: # case > border
        if y[i] > y[i-1]: #increasing
            if y[i] - delta < border: #Keep increasing till you hit border
                yblue.append(y[i] - delta)
            else:
                delta=delta+y[i] - y[i-1]
                yblue.append(border)
        else: #decreasing
            yblue.append(y[i]-delta)

plt.plot(x[:len(yblue)], yblue, color="tab:blue")
plt.show()
```

[image]

**USE CASE 2 - Blue line to stop at border2**

To stop the blue line at border2, you need to check if the blue line has touched/crossed border2 and break. You will need to add this check when line comes below border as well as when red line is decreasing. Updated code and plot below..

```
yblue=[]
delta=0
for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] < border2: #Less than border2, stop plotting
        break
    elif y[i] <= border: # In between, continue
        yblue.append(y[i] - delta)
        if y[i] - delta <= border2: ##Break if blue line touches border2
            break
    else: # case > border
        if y[i] > y[i-1]: #increasing
            if y[i] - delta < border: #Keep increasing till you hit border
                yblue.append(y[i] - delta)
            else:
                delta=delta+y[i] - y[i-1]
                yblue.append(border)
        else: #decreasing
            yblue.append(y[i]-delta)
            if y[i] - delta <= border2: ##Break if blue line touches border2
                break
           
plt.plot(x[:len(yblue)], yblue, color="tab:blue")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's great! Just what I needed! Thank you very much! But I also need the blue line not to be displayed further away if it intersects border2

Comment: Added Use Case-2 to answer your comment above - stop blue line at border2